# how to Dynamically Active tab with content for ui bootstrap tabs in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to dynamically active tab with content in angular js
my code is

```
<uib-tabset ng-if="pets_count > 0" class="petsTabs tab-animation">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, pet) in pets_list">
        <uib-tab heading="{{pet.pet_name}}" active="{{pet.pet_id == activePet}}">
            <div class="petsTabsContent" >
                <h4>
                    {{pet.pet_name}}
                    <small>
                        Boarding Dates: {{ pet.start_date | date : 'MMMM d, y'}} to {{ pet.end_date | date : 'MMMM d, y'}}
                    </small>
                </h4>
            </div>
        </uib-tab>
    </div>
</uib-tabset>
```

i have two variables pet.pet_id, activePet on base for these variables i have to active tab.
but it does not working i am new to angular js
thanks in advance
This controller

```
$scope.show_pet_function = function () {
    var pet_id;
    var action;
    pet_id = parseInt($('.pet_view_option').attr('data-pet_id'));
    action = $('.pet_view_option').attr('data-action');
    petowner_user_id =  parseInt($('.pet_view_option').attr('data-pet-owner'));
    var details = $scope.hidePetData;
    $http.post(CONFIG.APIURL + 'Pets/changePetHideStatus/', {pet_id: pet_id, action: action})
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.data.action == 'show_pet') {
                    promise = petlistFunction(petowner_user_id).then(function (response) {
                        $scope.activePet = pet_id;
                        angular.extend($scope.pets_list, response.data['pets_list']);
                    });
                    toastr.success(response.data.message);
                } else if (response.data.action == 'hide_pet') {
                    promise = petlistFunction(petowner_user_id).then(function (response) {
                        $scope.activePet = pet_id;
                        angular.extend($scope.pets_list, response.data['pets_list']);
                    });
                }
            });
}
```

This is response for pet_list object type array
[image]

Comment: post your controller

Comment: @sachilaranawaka updated

Comment: can you please post the `$scope.pets_list` array also

Comment: it is an object type array with a lot of data for every pet what do you want to see tell me i will share specific data for you

Comment: just show me the properties you used inside ne repeat

Comment: i have update the code and picture also

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be an issue with $scope binding, as you are pulling the data in then-able function.
So try by placing `$scope.$apply()` after the $http response.
For reference add it like this

```
angular.extend($scope.pets_list, response.data['pets_list']);
$scope.$apply();
```

Comment: angular.extend is working, don't need to add $scope.apply

Comment: Is your data is loading in view file?

Comment: no i have make function in controller from where i got data

Comment: Just try to add $scope.$apply(); after the angular.extend statement. And if it doesn't work, please share your HTML page screenshot.

Comment: its working for Angular JS end but there is a problem to make active tab for ui bootstrap tabs